# Uploading a StorageItemThumbnail to Azure blob storage from a Windows Universal app

Tags: azure, windows-runtime, azure-storage, win-universal-app, storagefile

I am building a Windows Universal app.

I have a [Windows.Storage.FileProperties.StorageItemThumbnail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemthumbnail.aspx) obtained from a [Windows.Storage.StorageFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) as the result of a call to [StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227213.aspx).

Now I need to upload the thumbnail to Azure blob storage.

The correct method appears to be `UploadFromFileAsync` or `UploadFromStreamAsync` on `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob`.

But the only documentation I can find for [UploadFromFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromfileasync.aspx) is misleading in my case. All the method overloads documented there include a [System.IO.FileMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/system.io.filemode.aspx) parameter, which is not available under Windows Runtime / Windows Universal. These are the two overloads actually available to me:

```csharp
    public IAsyncAction UploadFromFileAsync(StorageFile source);
    public IAsyncAction UploadFromFileAsync(StorageFile source, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext);
```

though I do not know where to find them documented.

How do I upload the `StorageItemThumbnail` to Azure blob storage using the `CloudBlockBlob`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be very straightforward:

```csharp
    public async void UploadThumbnailToBlob(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob blob)
    {
        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(thumbnail);
    }
```